# Probability distribution of sum of IID gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, physics, gaussian

I often see people say that if you have 2 IID gaussian RVs, say $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$, then the distribution of their sum is $\mathcal{N}(\mu_x + \mu_y, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)$.

This is only true when $X$ and $Y$ have the same units right, otherwise you can't even sum them to begin with without standardization?

e.g., if $X$ was some measure of distance in meters and $Y$ was some measure of velocity in $\frac{meters}{second}$, then you can't simply just add their means and variances together. That wouldn't make sense. You'd have to standardize them first so they're both unitless before you can do the above.

Comment: 'have the same units' - that's not really applicable to probability theory

Comment: I think you should look up convolution of random variables to understand how the parameters of the sum was obtained

Comment: @Alex I have looked up convolutions before, but I still want to think about this from a physical perspective. Adding 2 variables together that doesn't have the same units doesn't make sense physically, and I don't see why probabillity theory is exempt from that. Like what does the mean height of someone plus the mean salary of someone even mean?

Comment: You are talking from the point of view of physics/economics. Probability theory, roughly speaking, doesn't understand these terms.

Comment: @Iamanon The point is that adding things that have different units indeed doesn't make *sense* physically. But mathematically, there is no notion of units there. If you decide to add the things (whether it makes sense or not), you can do it -- it's not about probability. If I have x meters and y Pascals, I can write x+y. It won't mean anything if I try to interpret the result, but I can still compute the sum of two numbers.

Comment: I.e., the *numbers* don't have units. This of it as pairs "(x,meters)" and "(y, Pascals)" where x,y are just real numbers. You can compute $x+y$, but then it doesn't correspond to any meaningful pair $(x+y, unit)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion does not really have anything to do with random variables, but rather simply with interpreting units. If I tell you I have $10$ apples and $3$ oranges, then $10 + 3 = 13$, no matter what, but what $13$ **represents** is a question that is orthogonal to the mathematical question of what is the sum of $10$ and $3$.

If $X$ is a random number of apples and $Y$ a random number of oranges, then there is nothing that prevents the random number $X + Y$ from **existing**. The question of what $X+Y$ should **represent** is orthogonal to the mathematical question of what is the distribution of $X+Y$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent , $X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^{2})$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^{2})$ then  $X+Y \sim N(\mu_X+\mu_Y,\sigma_X^{2}+\sigma_Y^{2})$. [IID would force $\mu_X=\mu_Y, \sigma_X=\sigma_Y$ which is  not required here. Independence is enough]. There is no need to standardize the random variables for this.

[There are many ways of proving this and one way is to use characteristic functions. Use the fact that $Ee^{it(X+Y)}=Ee^{itX}Ee^{itY}$ and you would be able to supply a proof].

Comment: So this works even if $X$ and $Y$ don't have the same units? I don't quite understand that from a physics perspective. Summing up means of variables with different units doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I am not a physicist and I don't understand the origin of your doubt. But as far as Probability Theory is concerned there is no problem at all in proving this result.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a Multivariate Gaussian — assign each unit to a different dimension and then you have a random Gaussian vector. If there is no correlation between the two dimensions this reduces to each coming from its own Gaussian.